# Possible typo/error in Stack Overflow Research Portal 2016

Tags: discussion, survey-2016

Inside the [Survey Results](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016) in the [research portal](https://stackoverflow.com/research), there is a section about Programmers, Engineers, and Developers. The last category is "Full-Stack Overflow Developer." Was this intended?
[image: Full-Stack Overflow Developer]

I noticed there was both a Full-Stack Developer and Full-Stack Overflow Developer.

Comment: A reference to https://www.christianheilmann.com/2015/07/17/the-full-stackoverflow-developer/

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This was an actual option in the survey and was a reference to a post by Christian Heilmann titled [The Full Stack Overflow Developer](https://www.christianheilmann.com/2015/07/17/the-full-stackoverflow-developer/), lamenting the existence of some developers who work by copy/pasting stuff from Stack Overflow without real understanding and without trying to understand the code they are using.

[image: Fake O'reilly "Copying and Pasting from Stack Overflow" book cover]

Comment: I wonder how many knew what it meant... and still answered sincerely.

Comment: Ah. That makes a lot of sense. I was reading over it, and I thought it must've been a typo. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: That's hilarious. The sloth is so fitting XD